# how to use typescript Partial with class

Tags: typescript

we can do something like

```
interface A{
 name: string;
}

interface B extends Partial<A>{}
```

now `B.name` is optional

and...

```
class A{
 name: string;
}

class B extends Partial<A>{}
```

but this causes this error

```
'Partial' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here
```

note that I don't talk here about the concept of Partial classes in other languages such as `C#`

Comment: What would a "partial class" be at runtime?  The class `A` is a constructor that exists at runtime; it has an implementation, unlike an interface.  You can't just wrap it with `Partial`, you'd need to transform the actual constructor value in some way.  If you do that so that the compiler sees the properties as optional, then I can easily imagine runtime errors...  (more)

Comment: (continued) ...Right now your class `A` is nothing more than a single property (and you don't initialize it for some reason, please consider making this a [mre] that works in `--strict` mode without unrelated errors) so the problem isn't apparent.  [Here](https://tsplay.dev/NDVLOW) is one approach, but it explodes easily.  Could you please [edit] to clarify exactly what you expect to see in such cases?

Answer (score 1):

The type `A` and value `A` are different. The value `A` is a constructor for the type `A`. If you defined a type for constructors:

```js
type Constructor<T> = { new(...args : never[]): T }
```

The value `A` has type `Constructor<A>`.

You can then coerce it to a constructor of `Partial<A>` using a type assertion:

```js
class A {
 name!: string;
}

class B extends (A as Constructor<Partial<A>>) {
  f() {
    this.name = undefined;
  }
}
```